# Can Openvas scan itself?

Tags: security, ubuntu, server, openvas

Is it possible to install Openvas on Ubuntu 12 or 14 server and perform a scan the same server? I have only one server in my network and want to perform hosting vulnerabilities tests.

Kind of noob question but I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible. You should just enter the IP address of the external interface and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just do not recommend when doing other scans. Interestingly do in moments that OpenVAS is completely idle, because it some plugins generate a crash in itself and you have other appointments in the queue and is not accompanying person, for example, early in the morning, you just know that the next morning and lose quite a long time.

Leave this type of scan (scan of openvas itself to be the last in the queue scans)